# codeigniter: removing index.php not working in xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i can't access base_url/controller/method without index.php, i try to remove index.php using .htaccess but still not working.
[404 Page Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOR53.png)
but my another project is working with same setting in same xampp

this is my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sistem-informasi-bimbel/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

this is my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main/home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
```

this is my .htaccess file, i put it outside application folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

mod rewrite is enable on httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: After this settings you restart xampp ?

Comment: Yes, i restart the xampp after enable mod_rewrite

Answer (score 1):

This code is perfectly work for me.

You need to create a `gallery()` under main controller. same as below:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {


    public function gallery()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i do this, i created gallery() in main controller